# How to convert PLY file to SCN file supported by Apple SceneKit using AssimpKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I tried AssimpKit for the same but it provides the animation to the provided object. I want the provided file to be converted in .scn format and to be saved in document directory.

I have used the following code what it does is animating the provided file with the SceneKit. I would like to know if there is a way to get the object file exportable in document directory with .scn format using AssimpKit framework or any other SDK.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *bob = [docsDir stringByAppendingString:@"/Bob.md5mesh"];////Bob.md5mesh
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:bob]) {
        // load model
    SCNAssimpScene *scene =
    [SCNScene assimpSceneWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bob]
                postProcessFlags:AssimpKit_JoinIdenticalVertices |
     AssimpKit_Process_FlipUVs |
     AssimpKit_Process_Triangulate];

    NSLog(@"SCENE NODE: %@",scene.rootNode);

        // load animation
    NSString *bobAnim = [docsDir stringByAppendingString:@"/Bob.md5anim"];
    [SCNScene assimpSceneWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bobAnim]
                postProcessFlags:AssimpKit_JoinIdenticalVertices |
     AssimpKit_Process_FlipUVs |
     AssimpKit_Process_Triangulate];
    NSString *bobId = @"Bob-1";
    SCNAssimpAnimSettings *settings =
    [[SCNAssimpAnimSettings alloc] init];
    settings.repeatCount = 3;
    SCNScene *anim = [scene animationSceneForKey:bobId];
    [scene.modelScene.rootNode addAnimationScene:anim forKey:bobId
                                    withSettings:settings];

        // retrieve the SCNView
    SCNView *scnView = (SCNView *)self.view;

        // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene.modelScene;

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = YES;

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    scnView.showsStatistics = YES;

        // configure the view
    scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    scnView.playing = YES;
```